Hosting an asp.net WebApp available for employees of my department
I'm starting to build a webapp asp.net 6 on visual studio code, with specific needs of my company's department.
We have no contact with IT dept and don't want to, simply building things that would take too much time with dedicated IT project.
My question is : what is the best option to make my app available for my colleagues while we do not have possibility to deploy this solution on a server ?
Additionnal info : i haven't admin rights on my computer, so i cannot manage my firewall rules.

Azure / AWS / etc. Any medium-sized org or larger will have a company account you can request access to.

thing is i cannot send data from my company onto cloud without having a formal permission that would take much time.
Ideally, this add is managed and used within company

So... you can't run a webserver locally due to your firewall and you can't use a Cloud provider because of red-tape... my next-best suggestion is to find a cheap PC no-one cares about and set it up as a LAN server, assuming your local IT people won't get in the way - but if it's not a member of your on-prem AD domain then it probably won't be able to connect to useful local databases, etc. I suggest you ask your IT people to set-up an IIS box for you - if your org has VM infrastructure then it shouldn't take more than 10 minutes.

You don't write about the particular work context. Do consider that, while the organization's IT department may seem to be in the way, it may be there for a reason, and that doing shadow IT could get you in trouble.

Thanks @Dai for the suggestion, might consider ISS box even they have strict policy about allowing this stuff for non-it ppl.
MarkSeemann of course IT dept is here to help, i do agree with that. Problem is, if i ask for help on this, they will ask for dedicated IT project development, while my dept job is very specific. It would take months or year to release stuff

@Thibault_Km ...could you host it from home?

Technically it is possible to me, but i'm afraid they won't agree data leak on an external server... Sorry maybe there is no solution to this problem

you can put IIS on any machine that's a member of the domain and then use the machine's name as the URL.  Windows Authentication should be used and turn off anonymous access.  (This will create an "intranet" that anyone who's a member of the domain can use.)

@browsermator thanks ! any docs which i can refer to ?

I had an old bookmark here, but it might be a bit out of date: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-an-aspnet-website-on-iis/configuring-step-1-install-iis-and-asp-net-modules

Firstly, if you just want to host this application inside your computer, it contains some limitation:
1.Personal windows IIS contains the limitation that just allow 3 user access the website at sametime.
2.You need to have the permission to open the port to allow other member inside the same domain to access your computer.
As you said, you are inside the Intranet, I suggest you could directly running the asp.net core inside the one computer which could open the port by using asp.net core default host Kestrel.
No need to host it at the IIS, since personal windows IIS(not windows server system) contain the limitation.
More details about how to use publish and host using the Kestrel, you could refer to this article.

Thanks ! One question, how do i know if the computer has permission to open port to allow other member access WebApplication ? I would like to test things, but i'm afraid my computer shows "discover other network isn't allowed". I'm tired of this very restrictive cyber security

check you have the permission to modify the firewall.
